# Is there a way to loop through MATLAB's built in matrices (gallery)?

Tags: matlab, matrix

There is a number of built in test matrices in matlab, invoked by "gallery" function which requires a string with matrix name. Is there a convenient  way of getting list of all built-in matrices or another way to loop through all of them?

Comment: [The documentation for `gallery`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html) seems to say that you have to manually select from the list provided there. But they don't specify a way of getting that information from Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the test matrices is associated with a filename (`.m`) in the folder `toolbox/matlab/elmat/private`.

You can list the test matrices names with

```
filestrct = dir([matlabroot filesep 'toolbox' filesep 'matlab' filesep 'elmat' filesep 'private' filesep '*.m']);
filenames = {filestrct.name}';
testmat = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-2), filenames, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

It will give you a cell array of names. Each element can be retrieved by

```
 testmat{k}
```

Comment: Nice.  Didn't think of checking the MATLAB directory.  I just decided to copy and paste the names and put them into a cell array manually.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the source of `gallery`, there is basically one large `case` statement that checks to see what name you put into the function.  Because of this, there isn't a way to extract all the names programmatically.  You're going to have to copy and paste those names and get them yourself.  However, because I'm feeling nice, I've decided to go through that list and compile it into a cell array.  Here is the list for you in cell array format:

```
listNames = {'binomial','chebspec','clement','cycol','dramadah','gearmat',...
     'frank','gallery3','gallery5','gcdmat','grcar','invol','ipjfact',...
     'lehmer','lesp','lotkin','minij','neumann', 'orthog', ...
     'parter','poisson','redheff','riemann','rando','ris','smoke', ...
     'wathen','wilk', 'cauchy','invhess','leslie', 'chebvand', ...
     'chow','forsythe','kahan','compar','house','qmult','randhess', ...
     'condex','randjorth', 'circul','fiedler','randcorr','randcolu','sampling', ...
     'dorr','hanowa','jordbloc','kms','lauchli','moler','pei',...
     'prolate','randsvd','triw', 'krylov', 'toeppd', 'toeppen', 'tridiag', ...
     'normaldata', 'uniformdata', 'integerdata'};

%// Sort alphabetically just for kicks
listNames = sort(listNames);
```

Each kind of matrix has different parameters, so that'll be up to you to figure those out, but all names that `gallery` takes in are in the cell array above.  As such, you simply access the k<sup>th</sup> name by:

```
nameMat = listNames{k};
```